# PHP Javascript to store the items list and update action after click button

Tags: javascript, php

I have drafted one code for my situations, but it needs your help.
I have the html table listing items. Each have one approve button and reject button. When click button, it will store in the list or array. Then in the end if user click the save button. it will handle the store list or array.
Is there any sample code or any instructions to help me to do?

```
<?php 
$sel2approve=null;
function approve($temp)
{
    if($sel2approve==null)
        $sel2approve=array($temp);
    else
        $sel2approve=$sel2approve+array($temp);

}
$sel2reject=null;
function reject($temp)
{
    if($sel2reject==null)
        $sel2reject=array($temp);
    else
        $sel2reject=$sel2reject+array($temp);

}
?>

<a href=""> Aprrove </a><a href="">Reject</a> 

<a href="updateAll?approvelist=N%3B&rejectlist=N%3B"> Save</a>
```

Comment: On clicking `save` and `reject` you need to **temporally** `save` those items. You can't use simple variables as they `won't save` during refreshes. You should use `sessions` or `cookies`.

Comment: The problem is that your PHP code is running on the server (backend), and the user is clicking in the browser (frontend). When they click on one of your buttons, the page is going to refresh, and any data stored in local vars will be lost. You need to either implement a full PHP based approach or a also use some JavaScript on the client side. I would probably use JS for the Approve / Reject, and PHP for the save since that probably is stored in the backend.